# Font change: rn and m aren't the same

Tags: feature-request, design, user-experience

This is quite a simple thing, but something that actually bugs me quite a bit. Why is it that the font chosen on the Stack Exchange displays the letters rn (`rn`) and m (`m`) almost identically (rn m). Personally, the number of times people spell my pseudonym wrong is probably daily on days I'm active. This does actually cause problems as well, as @Lamu won't send me a notification if I've asked a question in the comments. This would mean I may well never go back to the question when/if the OP does respond.

Now, why people don't key <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>L</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>tab</kbd> I don't know, but still. Does this affect anyone else as well, out of interest? Perhaps not on your name but does it make for difficult reading for non-English speakers, or perhaps those that are used to non-latin languages? I could imagine that it might be difficult if you misread a word such as "learn" as "leam" and then couldn't work out what it meant.

Comment: You post to Windows-specific tags.  The designers at SO were not interested in making it look pretty on that OS, they chose Arial as the default font.  An ancient font that has interesting Google hits when combined with the words "scourge", "crime" or "bad".  That's easy to fix, even when the designers don't want to, but those users are unlikely to all adopt the fix.  Changing your username is by far the easiest way.

Comment: @HansPassant *"You post to Windows-specific tags"*? Do you mean that this is a problem only on Windows? I disagree, as I don't just use Windows hosts, and it looks the same on both (which you would hope for now a days). Although I use a Pseudonym here, are you saying those that use their real names should chaneg them too? That's seems rather harsh.

Comment: It does seem to depend on what you use to visit the site. Right now, using Chrome on Android, "rn" and "m" look different from each other to me.

Comment: It may well be a problem elsewhere, I don't get out that much.  If you can already see the readability problem yourself then you have more convincing reasons to pick another name.  Real names and dictionary words do have [less trouble](http://www.mrc-cbu.cam.ac.uk/people/matt-davis/cmabridge/) being recognized correctly.  I doubt anybody ever got "learner" wrong :)

Comment: Another user with this problem [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/636019/ildjarn).

Comment: The difference is obvious enough on Chrome iOS too, there’s very little chance of confusing the two from where I’m sitting, must be a platform/browser specific problem

Comment: Chrome, Firefox and Edge on Windows 10, no issues here, they look different.

Comment: Could probably be considered to be a duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272594/im-rnevius-not-mevius-a-font-kerning-issue-with-usernames

Comment: I think this issue was already pointed out elsewhere, emphasizing how problematic it could be for Maven users that their "Project Object Model" XML file is usually referred to as *"pom"* ...

Comment: People misspell my name *all the time*.  Even when the prompt exists.  I'd probably be in the same boat as you if I wasn't convinced that it's a phonetic typo more than a visual typo.  Kind of how you say something and you spell how it sounds rather than typing it out.  Admittedly I doubt you're going to get much traction on this feature request, but just throwing that out there.

Comment: I agree with the OP on this. In Firefox on Windows 10 in non-heading text "rn" and "m" overlay perfectly and are virtually identical bar the placement of the one black pixel used as the vertical stem of the "n". Move it one place to the left and you get "m". Even with good short-distance vision, they could easily be confused.

Comment: I'm on Linux and the OP's name looks like Lamu to me, so not really Windows specific. That said, I like Arial better than some other fonts I could name...